# How can I install autopep8 tool in Spyder in Anaconda?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I have Anaconda2, which come with Spyder.
I want to install an autopep8 for Spyder but I don't know which and how

Comment: have you tried googling "spyder autopep8"? First hit is a spyder plugin for me.

Comment: okay, but I don't know how to install it. If I try with pip gives me "no matching distribution found" error

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can install it using:

```
pip install spyder.autopep8
```

So in anaconda (apparently there is no conda build for sypder.autopep8 ) so you just need to make sure you have `pip` installed in your conda environment and then use `pip` to install it:

```
conda install pip
pip install spyder.autopep8
```

or if you want to install it directly from the github repo:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-autopep8
```

If you install directly from git, there is not way for it to give you a distribution not found error.

After that do shift+F8 in spyder to autopep8.

Otherwise, if you are using a `.yml` file for your conda environment, you just need to add

```
- pip
- pip:
  - git+ssh://git@github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-autopep8
```

to your environment file and then run

```
conda env update -f environment.yml
```

from the command line.

Comment: I've tryed "conda install spyder.autopep8", but I get "Package not found"

Comment: Oh. If there is no conda build for it you can use `conda install pip` and then `pip install spyder.autopep8`

Comment: I modified the answer to reflect that.